# Single class instance serving multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I have a singleton client class in my solution, which calls an external service/APIs. There are no locks inside this class (nothing protecting variables being accessed by multiple threads).

If this singleton instance gets request 1, and while handling that request, it gets another request (request2). What happens? Does it continue processing request1 to completion, then serve request 2? Or will it start serving request 2 at the same time which in turn might over-write any variables in this singleton class?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well it might or not, depends on its implementation we do not see

Comment: Please post a simple example of a class, perhaps removing everything except the essential parts. Variables aren't the problem - it's fields and properties. But we can't be sure we're speaking the same language until we see the code.

Answer (score 1):

When two threads concurrently execute a method on a single instance of a class, arguments passed to a method and variables defined within that method are not overwritten. The values of fields and properties, however, can be changed.

This class is thread safe:

```cs
public class Calculator
{
    public long Add(int a, int b)
    {
        var result = a + b;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The arguments (`a`, `b`) and the variable (`result`) are stored in the stack frame, memory which is allocated each time the method is executed. So the `result` variable exists for each method call. Two method calls cannot share or overwrite that variable.

Similarly, if this method gets called while it's already executing, the `a` and `b` arguments are not overwritten.

As a result, any number of threads can safely call the `Add` method on a single  instance of `Calculator`. They can do this concurrently. One execution does not wait for the other.

This class is *not* thread safe:

```cs
public class Calculator
{
    private int _a;
    private int _b;

    public long Add(int a, int b)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        var result = _a + _b;
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's a contrived example. The difference here is that calling `Add` modifies the state of the class, changing the `_a` and `_b` fields. It would be the same if these were properties instead of fields.

If two threads tried to execute this at once you would get unpredictable results. Right before the first thread adds `_a` and `_b` another thread might change the value of one of those fields.

---

This is the simple version. There are more complicated scenarios. Suppose, for instance, we pass a `List<int>` as an argument to a method. If another thread has a reference to the same list, both threads could try to modify it, or one could modify it while the other is reading it, all with unexpected results. How to manage all of that is outside the scope of this answer.

Here are a few takeaways:

- Don't add state to class (fields and properties that change after its constructor is called) unless it's needed. There are scenarios where we must, and in some cases it's the whole purpose of the class. But if you can choose between the examples above, always choose the first one.
- Whenever we pass around references to objects like lists or instances of our own classes, consider what would happen if two threads had access to that object. And then

  - Don't pass them around if they're not thread safe
  - Make them thread safe before they're passed around
  - Be very, very careful. This is the worst option because it puts a burden on us and future developers to simulate the behavior of the code in our heads and see potential problems. It's so much better to prevent problems than to figure out how to navigate around them.

Another way of describing it: Concurrency is like plutonium. It's powerful and useful, but we must always know where it is and make sure it never leaks.